# Rounding within a conditional format function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have the following code that formats my df correctly, only it changes the rounding of my values from being 2 dp to adding 4 zeros to each value. Anyone know how to adjust the function to not add the decimal places?

This is the table

```
data = ''
index = ['US 2yr','US 5yr','US 10yr','US Ultra']
columns = ['Total Positioning - Z Score',
         'Asset Manager Positioning - Z Score',
         'Levereged Fund Positioning - Z Score',
         'Dealer Positioning - Z Score']
table_6m = pd.DataFrame(data,index=index,columns=columns)

table_6m.iloc[0,0] = 1.72
table_6m.iloc[0,1] = 1.56
table_6m.iloc[0,2] = 0.65
table_6m.iloc[0,3] = -1.26

table_6m.iloc[1,0] = 0.02
table_6m.iloc[1,1] = 0.25
table_6m.iloc[1,2] = -0.11
table_6m.iloc[1,3] = 1.99

table_6m.iloc[2,0] = -2.75
table_6m.iloc[2,1] = 1.49
table_6m.iloc[2,2] = 0.17
table_6m.iloc[2,3] = -0.02

table_6m.iloc[3,0] = 3.03
table_6m.iloc[3,1] = -0.22
table_6m.iloc[3,2] = 0.85
table_6m.iloc[3,3] = -1.50
```

This is the function to do a cond format

```
def background_gradient(s, m=None, M=None, cmap='Oranges', low=0, high=0):
    print(s.shape)
    if m is None:
        m = s.min().min()
    if M is None:
        M = s.max().max()
    rng = M - m
    norm = colors.Normalize(m - (rng * low),
                        M + (rng * high))
    normed = s.apply(lambda x: norm(x.values))

    cm = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)
    c = normed.applymap(lambda x: colors.rgb2hex(cm(x)))
    ret = c.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % x)
    return ret


table_6m.style.apply(background_gradient, axis=None)
```

Comment: Maybe `lambda x: round(norm(x.values), 2)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the styler, I thought you were just trying to round the values in the df.

Answer (score 1):

The styler differentiates between the *actual* value and the *display* value. For this reason, regardless of the data stored in the DataFrame, you'll need to specify a [format style](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Formatting-the-Display) to prevent the default formatting behaviour.

Either set the `precision`:

```
(
    table_6m.style
        .apply(background_gradient, axis=None)
        .format(precision=2)
)
```

Or use a formatting function:

```
(
    table_6m.style
        .apply(background_gradient, axis=None)
        .format(formatter='{:.2f}'.format)
)
```

[image: formatted table]

Answer (score -1):

After you calculate `normed`, add

```
normed = normed.round(2)
```

This will round values to 2 dp.

Comment: This will not work. The styler will still pad to 6 decimal places regardless of the actual value in the DataFrame. Also modifying the `normed` series in the function will not update the DataFrame.